# What is the meaning of following line of python code?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

Please elaboarate the following lines of code

```
def lcs(X , Y):
    # find the length of the strings
    m = len(X)
    n = len(Y)

    l = [[None] * (n + 1) for i in xrange(m + 1)]
```

Comment: Have you executed the code to see what the value of `l` is?

Comment: Assuming the line you're asking about is the last one, what confuses you? The multiplication on a list? The list comprehension? This is pretty straightforward, if useless, Python code.

Comment: actually it is the part of the solution of longest common subsequence

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to adopt ways to figure this out yourself.

edit1: First thing you do is print(l) and see whats up.

This is a pythonesque way of creating arrays:

```
l = [[None]*(n+1) for i in xrange(m+1)]
```

and it could be written

```
l = []
for i in xrange( m + 1 ):
    l.append( [None]*(n+1) )
```

now its clearer right?

and then you could try to print(  [None] * 3 ) to see what this does.

and since the comment says len of strings. then X and Y are strings.

then pass some strings to the function and see what comes out :)